# Delphi DBGrid not showing data

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, firedac

I have a delphi form with TFDConnection, TFDQuery, TDataSource and TDBGrid. I want to show the data that my query gets (select * from table_1) and put it in my DBGrid.
I've made all the connections between the components, but after I launch my query (which returns 12 rows) in my DBGrid are shown 12 rows but they are empty. Apparentely I forgot something that prevents me from seeing my data in my DBGrid. Can you help me what I'm missing in my actions ?

- 1- Adding all components to the form.
- 2- Connect FDQuery with FDConnection, TDataSource with FDQuery, DBGrid with TDataSource.
- 3- Connection parameters succed in testing (the problem is not in my connection parameters)
- 4- The number of rows are placed in my DBGrid (12), but with no information visible.
- 5- If I loop through my FDQuery I can see all the information I need but that doesn't help me populate my DBGrid.

Comment: It should work. I just repeated all the steps: A TFDConnection, created connection to SQLite database, tested connection, even ran a test query in the connection dialog SQL tab. Dropped a TFDQuery, set the connection to FDConnection1 and SQL to the test query used before. Set FDConnection1.Connected to True, FDQuery1.Active to True, dropped a TDataSource, set the DataSet to FDQuery1. Dropped a TDBGri and set DBGrid1.DataSource to DataSource1, and the data appeared in the DBGrid.

Comment: Are the fields defined to be visible? I suppose you could set everything up then define the fields to be invisible.

Comment: And what happens if you explicitly give up the needed fields in your select statement instead of using 'select *' ?

Comment: @KenWhite -> The thing is I have to fill my connection parameters run-time not design-time and that's why I can't test it design-time.

Comment: @No'amNewman -> If I undersand correctly you mean that somewhere something happens that makes my fields invisible - after testing it showed me that all my fields are visible so this is not where my problem is coming.

Comment: @Copilot -> If I understand correctly you mean "select field1,field2,field3 from ..." instead of "select * from ..." : still not working :(

Comment: @Roman: That doesn't matter. Do it in a new, empty test app so you can figure out what the problem is first, and then you can apply the solution to your real application. It's much easier and quicker than posting vague details here and hoping someone will guess what the problem is you're experiencing.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok when I test things design-time in my test project everything is fine - so apparentely my problems come somewhere in run-time.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this:

Make your `TFDQuery` active explicitly in your OnShow code of your Form. Like this,

```
procedure TForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FDQuery.Active:= True;
end;
```

It works for me and hope it helps.

Comment: The DataControls which associates one control to another, may lose their settings at runtime.

Comment: The solution which I gave works for me. Otherwise it's bit hard to find out. May be you can try once again with a new project for this particular task, I hope it doesn't take much time to retry.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem (which I had the same), after you open the query, set:

```
datasource.dataset := Query
```

and the problem will be resolved.

Comment: If the DataSource's DataSet property is already set to the Query component (which from the OP's description it probably is), this will not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You would get the behaviour that you would see the correct number of rows in the DBGrid, but the grid's cells are empty, if the DBGrid's `DefaultDrawing` property is set to `False`.  if that's the case for your DBGrid, obviously just set `DefaultDrawing` to `True`.

Comment: +1. It's the only reason I can imagine for this behaviour too. But you realize this question is more than an year old, right? xD I mean, you probably won't get your answer accepted.

Comment: @GabrielF:  Thanks and I appreciate the +1.  My attention was drawn to the q by the posting of another answer earlier this evening.  I wasn't posting mine in the hope of getting it accepted, just to suggest a more plausible explanation of the behaviour the OP seems to be getting.  Otoh, I see he was here less than 7 hours ago, so presumably will be able to say soon enough whether that was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is old, but maybe it can help someone. In my case, the solution was: Deleting all the DBGrid columns that was created in design time, OR match the column's (*TColumn*) *FieldName* property to the EXACT field names as they named in the database tables.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else with this problem, here's the fix: make sure that the column names (not the Title) in the grid control match the field names in the query.  Once they're matched they should behave properly.

Comment: This is not correct.  A grid column has no `Name` property.  The correct answer is that the `FieldName` property has to match one of the FieldNames of the dataset'.  @tdiop's answer mentions this, so this answer doesn't add anything